# Pass a form from a custom template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to check whether a user is attending an event within a list of events. If They are, cool: say that they've 'Registered'. If not, throw a signup form into the template.

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_is_attending(context, event):
    request = context['request']
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]
    if profile in attendees:
        return "<a href='#' class='button'>Thanks for Registering!</a>"
    else:
        return "<form method='POST' action='/event/{{ event.id }}/register/'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{% with csrf_token as csrf_token_clean %}{{ csrf_token_clean }}{% endwith %}' ><input type='hidden' name='username' value='{{ request.user.username }}' /><button class='btn' type='submit'><div class='timeleft'>{{ event.date|timeuntil|split_timeuntil|safe }} left</div><div class='register-text'>Register<br/><span>for this Event</span></div></button></form>"
     # I apologize for the lengthy form
```

The template tag works(it correctly checks). However, it returns:

- `event.date|timeuntil|split_timeuntil|safe left | Register for this event` as a string when it should be: "4 days left| Register for this event"

and

- I get a `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted` error. due to it not passing through correctly?

So what are my options? Can I pass a form from a custom template tag? I don't really have use for a django form in this case, as it's literally just a button.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: `attendees = [a.profile for a in Attendee.objects.filter(event=event)]` this is wasteful. Try `if Attendee.objects.filter(event=event,a__profile=profile).count():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple tag is not parsed as a template. You should use an inclusion tag, and put both the HTML (plus the if/else logic) in the separate template.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a tag? Try put the logic into your template like that (untested)

```
{if profile in attendees}
    <a href='#' class='button'>Thanks for Registering!</a>
{else}
    <form> ...></form>
{endif}
```